# Push Notification is not working in UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

As I updated all the `Notification` methods in my `AppDelegate` Class. `PushNotification` are receiving when the app is open and in close mode. I facing the issue when my app is closed and I received notification and try to tap the notification, It opens the app screen however these lines of code are not called:

```
let remoteNotification: NSDictionary! = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary
        print("remoteNotification = \(remoteNotification)")
        if (remoteNotification != nil) {
            print("***************************************\n\n\n\n\n launchOptions = \(launchOptions)\n ***************************************\n\n\n\n\n")

         self.notificationHandlingFunction(remoteNotification)
        }
```

and when I want to see the logs it will not appearing in the `Log` list:

[image]

My device is attached with `Xcode` but not running.
In code I print `RemoteNotification` however it not showing when I search this keyword.
I am facing this issue in `Swift`.

How can I manage my `Notification` method when this case arise.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297594/uiapplicationlaunchoptionsremotenotificationkey-not-getting-userinfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to project > Capabilities, Turn on Background Modes and enable Remote notifications

[image]

and then in app delegates simply add following method

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        self.notificationHandlingFunction(remoteNotification)
}
```

will work for all cases