# Getting PushNotification userinfo (payload) by clicking App Icon without clicking notification on IOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I am working on push notification on IOS 10.  When App is inactive/closed and gets notifications I able to get the userinfo(notification payload) with

```
NSDictionary *info = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
```

But if I directly click the app icon (not notification badge) I am not able to find get the notification payload.  Referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297594/uiapplicationlaunchoptionsremotenotificationkey-not-getting-userinfo) and tried to access by writing to file in

```
 didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo
 fetchCompletionHandler:^(UIBackgroundFetchResult handler)
 { Logging userinfo with NSLog  to verify, but I don't see any log entry}
```

And reading it back at `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, but no luck.  Is there any other IOS method available for this use case?

Comment: see this for iOS 10 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10/39383027#39383027

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get push notification userInfo in this case, you must store it on server, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44694830/7405093)