# How to know if app user click on push notification ios?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push

I want to detect if user click on push notification to launch the app.or to get it in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement in your AppDelegate the method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the application was not running the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method gets called when the application starts and you can check the launchOptions parameters like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if (launchOptions != nil) {
         NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
         if (notification) {
             // Launched from push notification
         }

    }
}
```

If the application is already launched you can use this method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground  )
    {
         //opened from a push notification when the app was on background
    }
}
```

You can also check:
[Detect if the app was launched/opened from a push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393673/detect-if-the-app-was-launched-opened-from-a-push-notification)

Comment: What if application is already launched I need to handle both condition.

Comment: if app is coming from background to foreground , at the same time if app receive push notification , that time I would get the state as InActive. ( How to solve this ?