# detect if app was launched from tapped in notification Center or app icon with set key content-available =1

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I tried this: [Detect if the app was launched/opened from a push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393673/detect-if-the-app-was-launched-opened-from-a-push-notification)

But the difference is that I have set the key `content-available = 1` which means that the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` event is always executed not only when it is played in the notification center. How can I distinguish when the notification center or icon app is triggered?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, the posting may be useful to someone else. In the `didReceiveRemoteNotification fetchCompletionHandler` set variable `timeReceiveRemoteNotification = NSDate ()` with the date the notification is received. And in `applicationDidBecomeActive` I check that the time elapsed between the current date and the execution of the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` event is less than 1s. Because if the application is launched from the notification center the first method that is executed is `didReceiveRemoteNotification` then `applicationDidBecomeActive` and if it is launched from the app icon the event that is executed is only `applicationDidBecomeActive` and therefore the variable `timeReceiveRemoteNotification` stays with the assigned value of the Date of receipt of the notification, which was probably more than one second. In `applicationDidBecomeActive` the code is:

```
LaunchIconApp = true
        println (NSDate().TimeIntervalSinceDate (timeReceiveRemoteNotification))
        if(launchIconApp && launchNotification && NSDate().TimeIntervalSinceDate (timeReceiveRemoteNotification) <1)
        {
            println("Comes from the notification center")
            LaunchNotification = false
        } Else {
            println("Comes from the app icon")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app is not open i.e its not in the background. When you open app below method is called :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

You can write this line in the above method.

```
NSDictionary *remoteNotifiInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
```

The `remoteNotifiInfo` will always be not nil if the app is triggered by clicking on notification. If its nil this means that the app is opened by user by tapping on the application icon.

Comment: Thanks, what if it's in the background? How do I know if it was launched from icon app or notification center? Thank you for your answer