# Nativescript with OneSignal push notifications - GET the data on the app

Tags: push-notification, nativescript, onesignal

I´ve been searching a lot to find a solution but my problem as to do with some understanding of the mechanism, so i was wondering if someone could help me:

At this moment i´m sending push notifications **using the REST api** from OneSignal and it´s working...but i don´t know how to reach the **data** sent in order to tell the app to go to a specific place:

**My server side:**

```
public function sendMessage(){
        $content      = array(
            "en" => 'Nova Angariação'
        );
        $hashes_array = array();
        array_push($hashes_array, array(
            "id" => "like-button",
            "text" => "Ver",
            "icon" => "http://i.imgur.com/N8SN8ZS.png",
            "url" => "https://yoursite.com"
        ));
        $fields = array(
            'app_id' => "myAppId",
            'included_segments' => array(
                'All'
            ),
            'data' => array(
                "foo" => "bar"
            ),
            'contents' => $content,
            'buttons' => $hashes_array
        );
        $fields = json_encode($fields);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization: Basic my rest key'
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

        $resp = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $resp;
    }
```

**Now in my app(i´m using nativescript with OneSignal SDK):**

```
if (application.ios) {
    const MyDelegate = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
        __extends(MyDelegate, _super);
        function MyDelegate() {
            return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
        }
        MyDelegate.prototype.applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions = function (app, launchOptions) {
            try {

                **//i think it´s here where i have to handle the handleNotificationOpened but i don´t know how**

                TnsOneSignal.initWithLaunchOptionsAppId(launchOptions, 'my onesignal app key'); 
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error('error', error);
            }
            return true;
        };
        MyDelegate.ObjCProtocols = [UIApplicationDelegate];
        return MyDelegate;
    }(UIResponder));

    application.ios.delegate = MyDelegate;
}
```

How do i do this?

Thanks for your time
   Regards.

Comment: You may be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16393957/2708650) about handling push notifications received (in the background). Just another addition to your delegate.

Comment: Thanks for answering Ian, but that´s objective C syntax...how do you convert that in javascript to my nativescript app?, actually that´s a really old code..onesignal provides it in swift and i still don´t know how to convert that into my app

Comment: The signature for the [method you implemented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application?language=objc) should provide some clues here. There is a `*ios.d.ts` in the NativeScript repos (somewhere) that provides the description if you have trouble. They're pretty good about just mapping the methods as close to the native signature as they can.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the notification data upon app launch, then try this inside `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
if (launchOptions) {
  const userInfo = launchOptions.objectForKey(UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey);
  if (userInfo) {
     const aps = userInfo.objectForKey("aps");
     if (aps !== null) {
       // aps will be again a dictionary will have all data for the notification
     }
  }
}
```

Between `didReceiveRemoteNotification` also works, but when application is already in foreground.